# Is - a valid bitcoin address character

Tags: lost-bitcoins, p2pkh

I came across address like this **s-272edf45031dd498e7b3ae89e11ff21b**

In the [Address with Balance List](http://addresses.loyce.club/blockchair_bitcoin_addresses_and_balance_LATEST.tsv.gz)

Is the '-' a valid character?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, "-" is neither part of the base58 character set `123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz` used to encode non-segwit addresses, nor the [bech32](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0173.mediawiki#Bech32) character set `023456789acdefghjklmnpqrstuvwxyz` used for native segwit addresses.

This "address" appears to be Blockchair's [representation](https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/address/s-272edf45031dd498e7b3ae89e11ff21b) of a malformed output script that received ₿2,609 in a series of transactions on 2011-10-28.

[image: General info for "address" on Blockchair]

Bitcoin Talk user genjix [explains](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=50206.0) that the output script `76a90088ac` corresponds to a malformed standard P2PKH script which gave the address as `0`.

A P2PKH output script `76a914<pkhash>88ac` is composed of the following instructions:

```
OP_DUP (0x76), OP_HASH160 (0xa9), 0x14 (20 in hexadecimal, indicating a 20 byte push), <pubkey hash> (20 bytes), OP_EQUALVERIFY (0x88), OP_CHECKSIG (0xac)
```

whereas this [malformed script](https://blockstream.info/tx/111291fcf8ab84803d42ec59cb4eaceadd661185242a1e8f4b7e49b79ecbe5f3?expand) uses an `OP_0` instead of the pubkey hash:

[image]

```
OP_DUP (0x76), OP_HASH160 (0xa9), OP_0 (0x00), OP_EQUALVERIFY (0x88), OP_CHECKSIG (0xac)
```

Colloquially, these funds have been burnt by sending them to the address `0`, which is of course not a valid address. (Since `OP_HASH160` will always produce a 20-byte value, and that will never match `0`, `OP_EQUALVERIFY` will resolve to `false` for any pubkey and the funds are unspendable.)

Comment: Thanks. I noticed there are addressed with **0** and **l** as well. I assume all those are malformed and burnt as well.

Comment: Presumably. I was able to learn about this by searching the internet for the string rather than trying to look it up on a blockexplorer.

Comment: I just found out that **segwit bc1** is not base58 compliance.

Comment: Yes, native segwit addresses are encoded using Bech32/Bech32m. Bech32 is defined in [BIP173](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0173.mediawiki) if you want to read more. Bech32m is described in [BIP350](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0350.mediawiki).

Answer (score 1):

That is not a valid Bitcoin address. It may be an address for an altcoin, although `-` is not part of the Base58 character set. It may also be a non-standard address encoding.